# JQuery Offset returns 2 different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I have been struggling with this for more hours than I care to admit. I'm trying to place some elements on the page one right under the other using jQuery Offset but even though I'm passing the SAME offset values the rendered values to the screen are wildly different.  My jQuery code looks like this:

```
init: function (element, options) {
    var that = this,
    $field = $(element),

    ...

    var offset = $field.offset();
    that.ghostElement.offset({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left });
    that.suggestionsContainer.offset({ top: offset.top + $field.height(), left: offset.left });
```

but the html renders as like this:

```
<span class="autosuggest-ghost" style="top: 48px; left: 30px;"></span>

<div class="autosuggest-suggestions" style="top: 262px; left: 263.5px; display: block;">       
    <ul>
        <li><a blah...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

One would think that the autosuggest-suggestions would be top: 48 + 40, left: 30 but for some reason there much bigger.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

---

The Html elements are right next to each other as indicated and do not have different parents however; the autosuggest-ghost has a position: absolute and the autosuggest-suggestions has a position: absolute.  This is because the autosuggest-suggestions needs to float ontop of other elements on the page.

Comment: `offset()` is relative to the window, are you sure you're not looking for `position()` instead ?

Comment: Are the two elements really one after another in the way you have them in your question, or is the real document structure different?  I suspect they have different parent elements and `autosuggest-ghost` is within a relatively or absolutely positioned element.

Answer (score 0):

offset() is relative to the document, so the numbers are accurate but are being represented in strange ways... it all depends on how you have the rest of your elements and CSS set up.  Position() is relative to the parent object.  But that can still lead to some problems if you're not totally sure what's going on with your CSS.